# MSTest Out of memory exception

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, mstest, structuremap, rhino-mocks

Im having some problems running a test that creates a very large byte array (~4GB).

When i run it on a release/debug mode, everything works great, but when i run a test which initializes this array, i get OutOfMemory exception

```
for (int i = 0; i < 56000; i++)
{
    m_BlocksFree.Enqueue(new byte[65536]);
}
```

At first i thought since i have alot of tests that initialize this big array then i get an out of memory exception, but even when running a single test i get the same exception.

Im writing in C# & working with MSTest, Rhinomocks and structureMap, win7 64bit.

Thanks for the helpers :)

Answer (score 5):

Found the issue...

The test used QTAgent32 (32bit) and not QTAgent (64bit).

The solution was to select "Run tests in 64 bit process on 64 bit machine" in testsettings (under Host).

Comment: I had to go to Test->Test Settings->Default Processor Architecture in VS 2013 but doing so did fix my problem, so thank you.

Comment: Actually it didn't fix my problem, just made it show up less frequently.

Comment: We had a similar issue, maybe it will help someone else. When running Unit Tests, when a particular type was being reference/instantiated from an assembly, we would see the System.OutOfMemory exception. The referenced assembly had some very large resource files in it. Once we switched the test settings to x64, the out of memory issue was fixed. We also noted that ReSharper did not immediately honor the test settings change for VS's unit test. We had to change both ReSharpers as well (tho probably a reload of the solution after saving the test settings would have fixed it too.).

Answer (score 2):

It's help me:
editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32.exe"